# How to "refresh" python module structure?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a installed python module such as scipy (on osx). I can do for example:

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as li
li.lobpcg
```

and lobpcg gets recognized as a function:

In the directory
    $HOME//Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/
I have created subdirectory lobpcg2

```
-rw-r--r--   1 x123  staff  421 Dec 13 03:58 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 x123  staff  779 Dec 13 03:59 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  10 x123  staff  340 Dec 13 03:59 arpack
drwxr-xr-x   9 x123  staff  306 Dec 13 03:59 lobpcg
drwxr-xr-x  10 x123  staff  340 Dec 13 05:09 lobpcg2
-rw-r--r--   1 x123  staff  513 Dec 13 05:10 setup.py
-rw-r--r--   1 x123  staff  751 Dec 13 05:10 setup.pyc
```

With content:

```
total 104
-rw-r--r--  1 x123  staff    468 Dec 13 05:05 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 x123  staff    832 Dec 13 05:05 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  3 x123  staff    102 Dec 13 05:06 build
-rw-r--r--  1 x123  staff  19350 Dec 13 05:06 lobpcg2.py
-rw-r--r--  1 x123  staff  15118 Dec 13 05:09 lobpcg2.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 x123  staff    432 Dec 13 05:06 setup.py
-rw-r--r--  1 x123  staff    922 Dec 13 05:05 setup.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  4 x123  staff    136 Dec 13 05:05 tests
```

(the pyc files got created when I imported the *.py modules)
I can import lobpcg2 directly either when being inside the directory, or by setting a proper pythonpath to that directory. What should I do to be able to call it the following code without extra setup ?

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as li
li.lobpcg2
```

Comment: Why are you inserting stuff directly into your SciPy install?

Comment: I want to fix some issues in the implementation of a particular function. Where would I put it instead?

Comment: A package of your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "lobpcg2" to the **init**.py in its parent directory. See [this](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html).